# Wordpress : data exchange betweeen two plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce

I want to develop a website where teachers create exams and students pay money in order to pass these exams, so it's an e-commerce website where products are quiz.

The exams will be managed with a quiz plugin : i'll use Watu.
I still have no idea what e-commerce plugin I'll use.

What I want is to make exams as products so students can add them to cart, but I dont't see how can I do it : the e-commerce plugin manages its own products !!! Is there an easy way to do it ?

This is my idea: alter the quiz module so when an exam is created the script insert a row in the e-commerce table(s), so when I go to the e-commerce plugin I'll find a new product! But I think this is not a clean way !!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider setting up woo-commerce setting a link as a software product that will be delivered on checkout.

You could build a quiz answer table in sql, deliver a generic quiz (via a link sold in the store)

the quiz table could have a field for quiz_id and you could have their answers recorded as a text field.

so the link would be delivered digitally thru the store, your answers 1-100 a-d might look like this:

userid: xxxxx
autodate
test: 1
Answer:abadddaeababadddaeababadddaeababadddaeababadddaeababadddaeab

so one entry would contain all the answers on the test in question in one field.
once committed you could return a result based on a difference function from a pattern mask.
how many wrong answers in the simple query.

You then can store the answers and draw data based on what particular answers they got wrong.

they can also retake the same test at a later date and you can see each time how they did.

advantages of using a single text field means that you can use a single compare to pull the data and it's short to store.

Answer (score -1):

with a membership plugin. Give roles afther payments. Diferent roles for diferent levels of exam. It´s easy than make conexion with database.